# concept of Facebook's xd_receiver file

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, cross-domain, jsonp

I thought about building a simple API to let users grab some of our data.

Sooner or later you'll run into the cross-domain issue if you want to provide json or xml data. I don't want my users to put some curly proxy.php file on their own machines to solve that problem - so I was wondering - how is Facebook handling this issue?

What's the magic behind the xd_receiver.htm file (see content below)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there other solution to the x-domain problem? Without switching to JSONP?

thx

Comment: My dear in which are you living..... xd_reciever is now extermely past. Just read about graph api............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is simply used by the transport layer when using FIM based transport, but I don't think they rely on this anymore.

Either way, if you want to learn more about Cross Domain Messaging, then read [this article at ScriptJunkie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff800814.aspx), then take a look at the [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) library, which does everything for you - it even provides RPC.

Comment: @ezmilhouse Thanks, I'm the author ;)